# Django Admin - Fill inline field after autocomplete selection

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model with an inline model (see screenshot). The user selects a product via autocomplete and I would then like to fill in the purchasing price, that comes from the product.
[image]

Here are my models. The PoItem-Model:

```
class PoItem(models.Model):
    po = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    purchasing_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, default=0)
```

Here the product model. These ones here are listed in the autocomplete. And the purchasing_price from the product should be listed in purchasing_price field of the inline form, once a product has been selected via autocomplete

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    purchasing_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And here is my admin view. I have not listed the PurchaseOrder model as it's of no relevance:

```
@admin.register(PurchaseOrder)
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class PoItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = PoItem
        fields = ["product", "quantity", "purchasing_price"]
        extra = 1
        autocomplete_fields = ["product"]
        form = PoItemInlineForm
    
    inlines = [PoItemInline]
```

I would need some kind of even that gets triggered once a product has been selected.